# Is this possible to preapprove managed package subscriber users of connected app

Tags: profile, connected-apps, permission-sets

Is this possible to preapprove managed package subscriber users of connected app?

I tried to create both 1GMP and 2GMP to contain a connected app and a permission set that preapproves the access to the connected app.

However, when the package is installed into subscriber org, these policies are removed.

Even though on the packaging org or inside the source code for 2gmp, it is set to `Admin approved users are pre-authorized` and permission set is selected, when the package is installed, the policy is changed to `All users may self-authorize` and the permission set assignment is removed. Even if the policy is manually changed to `Admin approved users are pre-authorized`, permission set assignment is not restored and if we try to select it manually, it fails with an error

```
Cannot Modify Managed Component
The component you are attempting to modify is part of a managed package, and cannot be modified. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Click here to return to the previous page.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not possible.

Subscriber admin has to manually preapprove users and cannot select packaged profile or permission set, subscriber admin must clone the packaged permission set or create a new one and select it for preapprove and assign it for the corresponding users.

---

As an option, we could implement a button for admin to click.

This button click may deploy a new local unmanaged Connected App, make it preapproved and send its Consumer Key to the ISV.

Alternatively, admin user could follow a link and authorise the Connected App.